# JWT Bearer Authorization for web scraping using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, jwt

This is my first post on StackOverflow so please bear with me.

I am writing a function that makes a request via REST API and then returns the values, but I'm having trouble with the authentication part.

The authentication is a JWT bearer token, and is needed to retrieve the data (though I am not needing to log in so in that regard it is an unauthorised API).

```
def get__price(jwt, cookie):

    headers = {
        'authority': 'www.dextools.io',
        'pragma': 'no-cache',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'authorization': f'Bearer {jwt}', # HERE IS THE VAR I NEED
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'sec-gpc': '1',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'referer': 'https://www.dextools.io/app/uniswap/pair-explorer/0x0d4a11d5eeaac28ec3f61d100daf4d40471f1852',
        'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
        #'cookie': f'__cfduid={cookie}; ai_user=hizb^|2021-04-03T00:16:45.460Z; ai_session=5vAmv^|1617443356577.045^|1617443356577.045',
        }

    params = (
        ('v', '1.9.1'),
        ('pair', '0x0d4a11d5eeaac28ec3f61d100daf4d40471f1852'),
        ('ts', '1617443384-0')
    )

    try:
        response = requests.get('https://www.dextools.io/api/uniswap/1/pairexplorer', headers=headers, params=params)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"ERROR: {e}")
```

I've tried to make a request to the website `https://www.dextools.io` and get any JWT tokens, but it doesnt seem to work using Sessions.

Maybe it has no importance but I can find this JWT token on the browser when I go to `developer tools > Local Storage > (website url) > t` where `t` contains my eyJxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx token.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello seeing to the network requests of website I was able to get the data via below code but you might need to get the new password if website blocks it jwt token which is generated below is valid for like 6 to 8 mins you can re use the jwt token till that time and then you need to get new jwt token by calling that back login url like mentioned in below code.

Code:

```
import time
import requests

s = requests.session()

headersdict = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'https://www.dextools.io/app/uniswap/pair-explorer/0x0d4a11d5eeaac28ec3f61d100daf4d40471f1852',
    'Origin': 'https://www.dextools.io'}
s.headers.update(headersdict)
payload = {"id": "anyone", "password": "TfY6WC6F4L4+S6xwvPo8QoHlYZ50rK2DrJnEAWBoMqU="}#you can use this password to generate new jwt tokens if it blocks you check network requests and get this password again but i dont think they will block it that way.
s1 = s.post("https://www.dextools.io/back/user/login", json=payload)
jwt = s1.headers["X-Auth"]

headersdict = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'https://www.dextools.io/app/uniswap/pair-explorer/0x0d4a11d5eeaac28ec3f61d100daf4d40471f1852',
    'Origin': 'https://www.dextools.io',
    'authorization': f'Bearer {jwt}'}
s.headers.update(headersdict)
params = (
    ('v', '1.9.1'),
    ('pair', '0x0d4a11d5eeaac28ec3f61d100daf4d40471f1852'),
    ('ts', f'{time.time()}-0')
)
response = s.get('https://www.dextools.io/api/uniswap/1/pairexplorer', params=params)
print(response.text)
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: Haha, I love it! Brilliant.

Comment: Can you explain to me how you discovered this? Btw, they patched this entry point